# How do I change a JSFiddle to no longer be public?

Tags: sharing, jsfiddle

I created a new JSFiddle and made it public by entering a title upon saving it the first time.

If I try removing the title and then updating the script and setting the new version as the base, the original script which I made public still appears in my public profile with a `-0` at the end. Is there any way to remove this script from the public listing?

Comment: Just as a side note - all of the fiddles are public and still might be accessed using the same URL as before.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems that this is a caching problem. I just refreshed the list after several minutes and the script no longer appears in that list.

To remove a JSFiddle script from your public profile:

1. Open the script.
2. Open the Info tab on the left.
3. Delete the text in the title.
4. Press Update.
5. In this new version of the script, set it as the base version.
6. Wait several minutes for the script to be cleared from your public profile page.

As @zalun noted, the script is still accessible by anyone that has the URL to that script. This solution will simply remove it from your public profile.