# How do I make a script public in JSFiddle?

Tags: sharing, jsfiddle

If I have a private script, how can I make it public?

According to JSFiddle, the script must be the base version and have a title.

My current script has no title. I tried entering in a title and then updating the script. The problem is that it then no longer becomes the base version of the script. If I try changing it to become the base version, the title disappears.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that this is [also a caching problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/how-do-i-change-a-jsfiddle-to-no-longer-be-public/11027#11027), if you wait several minutes and then refresh your public profile, the script will appear there. Similarly, if you refresh the base script while editing it (make sure to save your changes!), the title should appear there as well.

To make a JSFiddle script public:

1. Open the script.
2. Open the Info tab on the left.
3. Enter in a title for the script.
4. Press Update.
5. In this new version of the script, set it as the base version.
6. Wait several minutes for the script to be visible in your public profile page.

Comment: Where can I set it as the base version? I thought I'd seen it in the past but now can't find it.

Comment: there is a button along the top menu bar with a star icon and the words "set as base"

Comment: Fork - change whatever you want to change - open info tab - enter title and description (optional) - update - set as base

Answer (score 6):

`jsfiddle.net/YourUsername/uvdNV/1` ← first version

`jsfiddle.net/YourUsername/uvdNV/2` ← second version

`jsfiddle.net/YourUsername/uvdNV/3` ← third version

...

`jsfiddle.net/YourUsername/uvdNV/n` ← nth version

`jsfiddle.net/YourUsername/uvdNV/` ← this is the base, you pick which version

You control the base to be any of the above.

Good practice is, when posting links, to use the base version so that you can update the script without having to update your links.

Note: if you update, a new version is created, the base stays at the same version and is not automatically updated to the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the url without the number at the end it will show that script which you chose to be the base version.

Say `jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/SJEe7/1` is my base version

Now `jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/SJEe7/` would show script `/1/`

When I create page `/2/`, page `/3/` and `/4/`

`jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/SJEe7/` continues to show script `/1/`

**But** if I set `jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/SJEe7/3/` to be the base version

`jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/SJEe7/` will show script `/3/` (!)