# How do I delete an anonymous JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I did a fiddle (public I think) and then logged in and forked the first one to get it into my fiddles. Now I want to delete the first fiddle.

Is it possible to delete a fiddle?

If yes, how do you do that?

I can understand if this is not possible by design as the first one is public and people could destroy valuable information this way, if that would be possible.

Comment: For a public fiddle, you can follow these [steps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/how-do-i-change-a-jsfiddle-to-no-longer-be-public) or mail to the jsfiddle admins

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this correctly but if you created the first fiddle anonymously before logging in and forking it under your login I would assume that you cannot explicitly delete the previous anonymous fiddle as no one owns it (How does jsFiddle know you owned the anonymous fiddle?). However, if you are talking about deleting a fiddle you created while being logged in then you can do that from your dashboard, hovering over the fiddle's title shows you a delete icon to the left of it you can click.

Comment: If the solution proposed by @FrançoisWahl worked for you, you could let him know so he could post his suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Looks like there's no way to delete an anonymously-created fiddle.

However, as far as I know there is no public index of anonymous fiddles, so if you never give the URL to anyone, there is very little chance anyone will ever see it again.

Still, don't ever go pasting sensitive data in JSFiddle… but of course you know that already.

Answer (score 1):

You can (now?)... maybe...

If you log in (create an account first if you don't have one) and visit the fiddle, on the left hand side an option will appear called `Removal request`, and below that you'll see a text link called `Submit a removal request` - clicking it will redirect to another page where you can indicate the reason for your deletion request.

The confirmation page said it can take some time but normally it's 24 hours.

*Update Oct 5, 2023: over a week went by and the fiddle is still there...*

*Update Oct 17, 2023: almost another 2 weeks went by and the fiddle is still there...*

*Last update Jan 12, 2024 (promise I stop here): over 3 months, and the fiddle is still there, so I guess this process isn't really working...*

Comment: I don't think that there will be any value in bumping this question by a new update saying something like "is still there". Please consider creating a chatroom and add a link to it in a comment. If you don't think to be adding a log entry frequently (chatrooms get frozen after 15 days of no activity), you might use the main chatroom, Google Fu, -> [chat].

Comment: @Rubén I didn't intend to go on with this forever, maybe one more update, then finish it until I can actually confirm that it's deleted. I was also considering removing my answer if it doesn't happen after some time.

Answer (score -1):

**Delete saved fiddles here**

1.

[image]

**Delete saved fiddles here**