# How do I delete a private Fiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I am new to using JSFiddle.  I've looked at the limited [JSFiddle Docs](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/), but can't find anything that tells me how to delete a private Fiddle.

I found one Stack Exchange question that said to use "Removal request," but that action is not showing in the view of All My Fiddles or the one I want to delete.

Is there a way to delete private Fiddles I no longer need?

Update: Thanks for the continuing thoughts. I thought the fiddles I created where private because the dot in front of "private fiddle" did not appear to be a button.  So, all of the fiddles I created before becoming a supporter were public.  In any case, now that I am a supporter, I still don't see a way to delete a fiddle, whether public or private.  I've taken a few partial screenshots so you can see what I am seeing without showing too much of my personal stuff.  Beyond this, I don't know what else I can say/provide.  My question seems pretty straightforward, though maybe there is some other non-obvious thing I'm missing.

[image: All Fiddles]
[image: Private Fiddle Screen]
[image: Public Fiddle Screen]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to confirm that you are a "[JSFiddle supporter](https://jsfiddle.net/extra/)" (have a paid subscription) and not simply using the term *private* incorrectly.

Comment: Please also [edit] to include a link to the Stack Exchange question you refer to in the question.

Comment: I do not have a paid subscription to JSFiddle.  I didn't realize that was required.  Here's a link to the Stack Exchange question I referenced: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51553/how-do-i-delete-an-anonymous-jsfiddle#:~:text=If%20you%20log%20in%20(create,the%20reason%20for%20your%20deletion

Comment: I just became a supporter, but still don't see how to delete my fiddles.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include important details, don't put them in comments.  In addition to those details that should be added to your question, please edit it for clarity.  For example, since private Fiddles can be created by *supporters*, and you were not a supporter, you must not have created a private Fiddle, and therefore there is no private Twiddle that needs to be deleted.  Since you obviously have a problem it must be something else that you have clearly shared.